# PHP Notice : undefined offset : 3 in my array

Tags: php, arrays, string

```php
*/

// File called with:
// e_PLUGIN_ABS."log/log.php?referer=' + ref + '&color=' + colord + '&eself=' + eself + '&res=' + res + '\">' );\n";
// referer= ref
// color= colord
// eself= eself 
// res= res
// err_direct - optional error flag
// err_referer - referrer if came via error page
define("log_INIT", TRUE);


$colour = strip_tags((isset($_REQUEST['color']) ? $_REQUEST['color'] : ''));
$res = strip_tags((isset($_REQUEST['res']) ? $_REQUEST['res'] : ''));
$self = strip_tags((isset($_REQUEST['eself']) ? $_REQUEST['eself'] : ''));
$ref = addslashes(strip_tags((isset($_REQUEST['referer']) ? $_REQUEST['referer'] : '')));
$date = date("z.Y", time());
$logPfile = "logs/logp_".$date.".php";


// vet resolution and colour depth some more - avoid dud values
if ($res && preg_match("#.*?((\d+)\w+?(\d+))#", $res, $match))
{
  $res = $match[2].'x'.$match[3];
}
else
{
  $res = '??';          // Can't decode resolution
}

if ($colour && preg_match("#.*?(\d+)#",$colour,$match))
{
  $colour = intval($match[1]);
}
else
{
  $colour='??';
}


if ($err_code = strip_tags((isset($_REQUEST['err_direct']) ? $_REQUEST['err_direct'] : '')))
{
  $ref = addslashes(strip_tags(isset($_REQUEST['err_referer']) ? $_REQUEST['err_referer'] : ''));
  $log_string = $err_code.",".$self.",".$ref;
// Uncomment the next two lines to create a separate CSV format log of invalid accesses - error code, entered URL, referrer
//  $logname = "logs/errpages.csv";
//  $logfp = fopen($logname, 'a+'); fwrite($logfp, $log_string."\n\r"); fclose($logfp);
  $err_code .= ':';
}

if(strstr($ref, "admin")) 
{
    $ref = FALSE;
}

$screenstats = $res."@".$colour;
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$ip = getip();

$oldref = $ref; // backup for search string being stripped off for referer
if($ref && !strstr($ref, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) 
{
  if(preg_match("#http://(.*?)($|/)#is", $ref, $match)) 
  {
    $ref = $match[0];
  }
}

$pageDisallow = "cache|file|eself|admin";
$tagRemove = "(\\\)|(\s)|(\')|(\")|(eself)|(&nbsp;)|(\.php)|(\.html)";
$tagRemove2 = "(\\\)|(\s)|(\')|(\")|(eself)|(&nbsp;)";

preg_match("#/(.*?)(\?|$)#si", $self, $match);
$match[1] = isset($match[1]) ? $match[1] : '';
$pageName = substr($match[1], (strrpos($match[1], "/")+1));
$PN = $pageName;
$pageName = preg_replace("/".$tagRemove."/si", "", $pageName);
if($pageName == "") $pageName = "index";

$pageName = $err_code.$pageName;            // Add the error code at the beginning, so its treated uniquely

if(preg_match("/".$pageDisallow."/i", $pageName)) return;


$p_handle = fopen($logPfile, 'r+');
if($p_handle && flock( $p_handle, LOCK_EX ) ) 
{
  $log_file_contents = '';
  while (!feof($p_handle))
  {  // Assemble a string of data
    $log_file_contents.= fgets($p_handle,1000);
  }
  $log_file_contents = str_replace(array('<'.'?php','?'.'>'),'',$log_file_contents);
  if (eval($log_file_contents) === FALSE) echo "error in log file contents<br /><br /><br /><br />";
}
else
{
  echo "Couldn't log data<br /><br /><br /><br />";
  exit;
}


$flag = FALSE;
if(array_key_exists($pageName, $pageInfo)) 
{  // Existing page - just increment stats
  $pageInfo[$pageName]['ttl'] ++;
}
else 
{  // First access of page
  $url = preg_replace("/".$tagRemove2."/si", "", $self);
  if(preg_match("/".$pageDisallow."/i", $url)) return;
  $pageInfo[$pageName] = array('url' => $url, 'ttl' => 1, 'unq' => 1);
  $flag = TRUE;
}

if(!strstr($ipAddresses, $ip)) 
{   /* unique visit */
  if(!$flag) 
  {
    $pageInfo[$pageName]['unq'] ++;
  }
  $siteUnique ++;
  $ipAddresses .= $ip.".";      // IP address is stored as hex string
  require_once("loginfo.php");
}

$siteTotal ++;
$info_data = var_export($pageInfo, true);
//$date_stamp = date("z:Y", time());            // Same as '$date' variable

$data = "<?php

/* e107 website system: Log file: {$date} */

\$ipAddresses = '{$ipAddresses}';
\$siteTotal = '{$siteTotal}';
\$siteUnique = '{$siteUnique}';

\$pageInfo = {$info_data};

?>";

if ($p_handle)
{
  ftruncate( $p_handle, 0 );
  fseek( $p_handle, 0 );
  fwrite($p_handle, $data);
  fclose($p_handle);
}



function getip($mode=TRUE) 
{
  if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) 
  {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    if (preg_match("#^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})#", getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'), $ip3)) 
    {  
      $ip2 = array('#^0\..*#', 
               '#^127\..*#',                            // Local loopbacks
               '#^192\.168\..*#',                       // RFC1918 - Private Network
               '#^172\.(?:1[6789]|2\d|3[01])\..*#',     // RFC1918 - Private network
               '#^10\..*#',                             // RFC1918 - Private Network
               '#^169\.254\..*#',                       // RFC3330 - Link-local, auto-DHCP 
               '#^2(?:2[456789]|[345][0-9])\..*#'       // Single check for Class D and Class E
               );
      $ip = preg_replace($ip2, $ip, $ip3[1]);
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  }
  if ($ip == "") 
  {
    $ip = "x.x.x.x";
  }
  if($mode) 
  {
    $ipa = explode(".", $ip);
    return sprintf('%02x%02x%02x%02x', $ipa[0], $ipa[1], $ipa[2], $ipa[3]);
  }
  else 
  {
    return $ip;
  }
}

?>​
```

> ERROR CODED : PHP Notice : undefined offset : 3 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\oss_plugins\log\log.php on line 202

Below is the log.php file in wwwroot folder : line 202 is the 3rd line from the

bottom where it states

```
(return sprintf('%02x%02x%02x%02x', $ipa[0], $ipa[1],
```

$ipa[2], $ipa[3]);

Comment: That's a LOT of code. Which one is line 202?

Comment: That error means there isn't a fourth element to the array `$ipa`.  If you `var_dump($ipa)` you should see the information in it, in which you can start debugging.

Comment: Line 202 is the line that has :  return sprintf('%02x%02x%02x%02x', $ipa[0], $ipa[1], $ipa[2], $ipa[3]);

Answer (score 1):

The length of your array `$ipa` is 3 then' you don't have $ipa[3].

replace your line 202 with this:

```
return sprintf('%02x%02x%02x', $ipa[0], $ipa[1], $ipa[2]);
```

If you want use your line 202:

```
return sprintf('%02x%02x%02x%02x', $ipa[0], $ipa[1], $ipa[2], $ipa[3]);
```

You must check that your `$ip` must be like this

> x.x.x.x

the error is because the format is

> x.x.x

Check your code.

Comment: @marvinmensah replace your line 202 with this line

Comment: I am now getting this  :  PHP Warning : sprintf (): Too few arguments in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\oss_plugins\log\log.php on line 202

Comment: @showdev thanks, I edit my answer with more info

Comment: The whole issue is : we migrated IIS from windows server 2003 to windows server 2012r2. the index page comes up alright but the menu items doesnt come up.

Comment: @marvinmensah I edit my answer check now and see the update

Comment: The same issue exist.

Comment: What would cause this problem ? is there a page that needs to be edit ? if the menu items (Listings ) are not displaying at the page .

Comment: @marvinmensah what you expect as output?

Comment: The output expected is the page with the menu items

Comment: @marvinmensah and which is the problem with my answer? I edit the answer.

Comment: I did as you stated but it still exist. the page comes up but no menu Items